# How to make server instance?

Tags: linux

Is there any way to divide the big server in small small server instance like i have 32gb RAM and 64 Ip's and 2 Tb HDD server form digital ocean.

Example

2 GB RAM 40GB 4 ips in instance 1.(install Ubuntu)

same config in instance 2.(centos)

same config in instance 3(any other OS)

and so on..as possible

I try opennebula but not succeed.

Comment: What? You want to have one big DO instance and split this into smaller ones? Why? Why not just launch  a number of smaller instances to start with? If you run nested virtualization, you just end up with bad performance...

Comment: @Sven is right, virtualizing an already virtualized server makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

You should not nest virtualisations. Especially on a something that is already a cloud provided host.

The whole point of services like Digital Ocean, AWS, Azure, Google Cloud, is so you don't have to bother with this. You just spin up three droplets/EC2/virtual machines/compute instances and configure each machine the way you want it.